# InfluxDB: unrecognized service

Tags: ubuntu, time-series, windows-subsystem-for-linux, influxdb

I tried to follow the tutorial to run InfluxDB on WSL Ubuntu. But when I tried to run the service by

```
sudo service influxdb start
```

it shows:

> influxdb: unrecognized service

Answer (score 3):

On WSL Ubuntu, you can manually run the InfluxDB daemon with:

```sh
influxd &
```

The ampersand at the end makes the daemon run in the background, so you can still execute commands after launching it. You can also close the WSL window, and the daemon will keep running.

Note: you can accidently run multiple instances of the InfluxDB with this method; you can check that none is running with:

```sh
ps -A | grep influxd
```